# Maven archetype

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

Why this works(and then asks step by step arguments which I can define manually)

```
C:\Users\userName>mvn archetype:generate
```

And this doesn't with arguments already specified? (it is example from 
http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html)

```
C:\Users\userName>mvn archetype:generate \ -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes \ -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app \ -DartifactId=my-app

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.124s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Aug 20 22:11:56 BST 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/122M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (C:\Users\userName. Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1
```

The first approach also doesn't find POM, but then it creates everything itself...

Comment: You didn't specify the maven version and you didn't run -X to see what actually happened, so it's not really possible to see this as an answerable question.

Comment: well, below there is the answer resolved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tried running your command.  When I remove the instances of \ it works fine for me.

Comment: exactly and why do I find out this from you not from Maven which puts in its examples instances of '\' and not only maven other sources too?  :-\  . Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

theotherian answered your question correctly. Here's some additional information. The backslashes in your command were line continuations. The example you copied from http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html was written on several different lines. The \ indicates that the command is meant to be all on one line, but was broken up for the sake of readability and screen space. If they weren't there and you just copied and pasted it into a command prompt, every line would be interpreted as a separate command.